# arduino adafruit motor shield

Tags: c++, linux, websocket, arduino

I just bought a new arduino adafruit motorshield because i needed to control 4 dc motors and it seemed to be the right decision. My arduino IDE is currently on a linux Virtual Box because i needed a specific library that I could only find on linux...The code below is supposed to receive data from websockets (that is working ) but when i use the Adafruit motor library something simply doesnt work...a humming sound comes out of the motors, but no actual movement.
(btw the "x" and "y" coordinates are being printed on the Serial Port)

```
 #include <AFMotor.h>
int x = -10;
int y = -10;
int b = 0;
AF_DCMotor motor_shoulderx(1);
AF_DCMotor motor_shouldery(2);
AF_DCMotor motor_elbow(3);
AF_DCMotor motor_wrist(4);
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
 if (Serial.available())
 { if (b == 0)
   { x = Serial.read();
   b =1;
   }
   else {
     y = Serial.read();
     b = 0;
   }
   if (x != -10){
   Serial.println("x is:");
   Serial.println(x);
   if(x > 200) {
     motor_shoulderx.run(FORWARD);
   }
   else {
     motor_shoulderx.run(BACKWARD);
   }
   }
   if (y != -10){
   Serial.println ("y is:");
   Serial.println (y);
   if (y > 200){
     motor_shouldery.run(FORWARD);
     motor_elbow.run(FORWARD);
     motor_wrist.run(FORWARD);  }
     else {
     motor_shouldery.run(BACKWARD);
     motor_elbow.run(BACKWARD);
     motor_wrist.run(BACKWARD);  

     }

   }


}}
```

Comment: Are you allowing time for the motors to ramp up or are you demanding they start at a specific velocity?  Too much, too fast at the beginning may cause the motors to hum.  Try advancing the motors slowly, i.e. slow acceleration.

Comment: Sounds like a power supply issue, what's your power source?